# How to generate random number of flops in system verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Am trying to add a random number of flops in the range between 0-10 flops. But facing an issue while the random number is 0.
Expecting data shouldn't be flopped if the random value is 0. Can you please suggest your comments.

Code:

```
module tx_delay_bmod_1(clk, i_tx_data,o_tx_data);
parameter CH_NUM = 4;

input clk;
input  i_tx_data;
output reg  o_tx_data;
int DELAY;
bit o_tx_data_tmp[100];

  int random_flop_cnt;
  int seed_num,ntb_random_seed;

  initial
     random_flop_cnt = (($urandom(CH_NUM )%10) + ((CH_NUM/4)*10));


always@(negedge clk) begin
if (random_flop_cnt==0) o_tx_data = i_tx_data; 
    else begin
      for(int i=0; i<random_flop_cnt; i++) begin
                if(i==0)
                o_tx_data_tmp[0] <= i_tx_data;
                else o_tx_data_tmp[i] <= o_tx_data_tmp[i-1];
                if(i==(random_flop_cnt-1))
                 o_tx_data <= o_tx_data_tmp[i];
      end 
      end
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raz says: you have the one register inside the clock code (and you use '=' instead of '<=' for that one.) You define 100 bits and chain up only the ones you need. This means the rest is unused and gets optimized away.

There is no need at all to have a loop inside the always block. Knowing that unused registers are removed you could chain all of them up and pick an output:

```
bit [99:0] o_tx_data_tmp;

always@(negedge clk)
    o_tx_data_tmp <= {o_tx_data_tmp[98:0],i_tx_data}; 

assign o_tx_data = random_flop_cnt==0 ? i_tx_data : o_tx_data_tmp[random_flop_cnt-1];
```

The main advantage is readability, especially as you are doing something out of the ordinary (using a random number of registers) which may easily confound the arbitrary reader.

I assume you know that this is behavioral only.

Answer (score 0):

On `flop_cnt == 0` you still will get a flop since you've coded that into an `always` block sensitive to clock (and thus, with this 1 assignment it will synth into a flop). You can consider replacing it with a direct `assign` within a `generate` block, i.e. `if 0 -> use assign else -> use an always block` (block level solution).

Or if there is no need to instantiate this block if there is no delay you can constrain your `flop_cnt` generation to produce numbers greater than `0`. Also, you won't instantiate this block at all, just route the signals on the top level differently (architectural solution).